# Using WHM, is there a way to batch make and download backups?

Tags: backup, redhat

I've got 10 accounts on one server. I want to make a full cpanel backup of each one and download them all to my external hard drive.

I do this manually, individually, which takes about an hour.

On a system using WHM (on a RedHat server), is there a way to batch make and download cpanel backups?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you have shell access then you can write shell script to backup all the accounts and put in one safe directory , from where you can download all of them